# Server error in IIS because of session state line in web.config

Tags: iis, server-error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
> Source Error:
>
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FAMS\fams\web.config    Line: 51
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4682.0

Line: 51 is this code

```
sessionState timeout="480"
```

I have tried by setting change but it is not resolved.

Comment: “ This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS” is exactly the mistake you made.

Answer (score 0):

Some elements of web.config are only allowed at "root" level, and that's probably what his problem is, besides, you can try to set the session in global.asax file instead web.config.